# How to send data from UDP port to lora sensor node?

Tags: python, udp, simulation, raspberry-pi3, lorawan

I am trying to send data from simulink then using UDP sending this data to raspberry. The data in raspberry pi was displayed correctly. But, when I am trying to send the UDP data to lora it was not able to send. Can someone help me how to fix the code. P.S. I am not expert in programming, I am just starting to learn everything. Thank you. BTW, I just got the basic code of sending data from github. The idea here is raspberry pi will accept data from another machine through UDP protocol. Then, the data will be unpack in raspberry pi, those data will be transmitted using lora piHat going to the gateway, then to network server.

```
from sys import exit
from time import sleep
from rak811.rak811 import Mode, Rak811
from ttn_secrets import APP_EUI, APP_KEY
import socket, struct, os
import numpy as np
import struct
import socket
lora = Rak811()
      
print('Setup')
lora.hard_reset()
lora.mode = Mode.LoRaWan
lora.band = 'AS923'
lora.set_config(app_eui=APP_EUI, app_key=APP_KEY)
print('Joining')
lora.join_otaa()
lora.dr = 5
IP = ""
PORT = 50000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((IP, PORT))
try:
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        data = struct.unpack('dddddddddd', data)
        lora.send(data[0])
        print("x1", data[0])
        sleep(0)
except
    pass
print('Cleaning up')
lora.close()
exit(0)
```

Comment: What is the code you are showing? Is it the rasperrypi LoRaWAN node?

Comment: yes, it is. I am using rak811 lora piHat and rak7240 lora gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved.

```
while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        data = struct.unpack('dddddddddd', data)
        x1 = format(data[0], '.4f')
        lora.send(x1)
        print("x1", x1)
        sleep(0)
```

I think the module won't send the float data type.